# how to set container ulimits in Container-Optimized OS

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-container-os

I need to set ulimits on the container. For example, `docker run --ulimit memlock="-1:-1" <image>`. However, I'm not sure how to do this when deploying a container-optimised VM on Compute Engine as it handles the startup of the container.

I'm able to deploy a VM with options like --privileged, -e for environment variables, and even an overriding CMD. How can I deploy a VM with ulimits set for the container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I received an official reply:

> Unfortunately the Containers on Compute Engine feature does not currently support setting the ulimit options for containers.
>
> A workaround would be to set ulimit inside the container. For example: 
>   gcloud beta compute instances create-with-container INSTANCE --zone=ZONE --container-image=gcr.io/google-containers/busybox --container-privileged --container-command=sh --container-arg=-c --container-arg=ulimit\ -n\ 100000
>
> Unfortunately this method requires running the container as privileged.
>
> Best regards,...

This reply gave me inspiration to do the following. Create a wrapper script that is referred to from your docker image's ENTRYPOINT. Within this wrapper script, set the ulimit(s) prior to starting the process(es) subjected to the ulimit(s).

As a quick example:

#### $HOME/example/wrapper.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

# set memlock to unlimited
ulimit -l unlimited

# start the elasticsearch node 
# (found this from the base images dockerfile on github)
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh eswrapper
```

#### $HOME/example/Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
COPY wrapper.sh .
RUN chmod 777 wrapper.sh
ENTRYPOINT ./wrapper.sh
```

#### local image build

`docker image build -t gcr.io/{GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}/example:0.0.0 $HOME/example`

#### deploy to gcr.io

`docker push gcr.io/{GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}/example:0.0.0`

#### create an instance via gcloud

```
gcloud beta compute instances create-with-container example-instance-1 \
    --zone us-central1-a \
    --container-image=gcr.io/{GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID}/example:0.0.0 \
    --container-privileged \
    --service-account={DEFAULT_COMPUTE_ENGINE_SERVICE_ACC_ID}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
    --metadata=startup-script="echo 'vm.max_map_count=262144' > /etc/sysctl.conf; sysctl -p;"
```

Note the following. The above startup script is only necessary for running a container of this image. The service account is necessary for pulling from your private google container registry. The --container-privileged argument is imperative as running the container with privileged is required to set ulimits  within it.

#### verifying ulimits are set for your process(es)

On the vm HOST, `ps -e` and find the PID(s) of the process(es) that were executed within your wrapper script. In this case, find the PID whose command was java. For each PID, `cat /proc/{PID}/limits`. In this case, I only set memlock to unlimited. You can see that it is indeed set to unlimited.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be a document for setting ulimit when [creating a Container Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance) or in the doc for [Configuring Options to Run Container](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers).

Currently, it doesn't seem to be supported having the option of automatically setting ulimit of containers when deploying a container-optimised VM as in the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/create-with-container). You can submit a feature request for that [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under 'Compute'. The document on [Configuring Options to Run Container](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers) doesn't include that either.

However, you can [run containers](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-container-instance) on a Container-Optimized OS (COS) instance. Thereby, you can run a docker with setting ulimit like [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit).

Comment: Thanks for your response! See my answer below. It seems to be simpler than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the following.

From within the VM or from a start script for the Container Optimized OS:

```
sudo echo "vm.max_map_count=262144" | tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```